# Registered services not found in DI engine when Xamarin app published in Release mode

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm writing an Android Wear app using Xamarin. I'm using the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` library to handle service dependency injection in my app. It works completely fine when I run the app in Debug mode through Visual Studio (Ctrl + F5), on my actual smartwatch. The app functions correctly and everything. When I publish the app using the "Archive..." function of the Xamarin toolset and then sideload the published version onto my Smartwatch, however, the app crashes at startup with an exception stating `System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'My.Library.SomeManager' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.`. This spawns from a call to `IServiceProvider.GetService` for the `SomeManager` type.

I don't know why this would be. I'm logging to logcat when I register the services, and can see them being registered in the published version, but for some odd reason, the dependency injection engine is not able to find them. I don't know enough about the inner workings of Xamarin to choose a direction to troubleshoot this. Does anybody know what would be causing this odd behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Release configuration has the Linker set to something *other* than `None`?

Classes, constructors and/or methods that are only referenced via reflection calls for activation and used via interfaces (typical for DI) can not be seen by the static analysis that the Mono Linker performs and thus are stripped from the assembly(s) in order the get the final app bundle size down to a "acceptable" size.

Note: This process is comparable to the Proguard tool, and its replacement,`R8`,  used to strip un-used Java code and has the some "limitation" and most of my `Xamarin.Android` projects end up with a custom Mono linker and Proguard/R8 config file.

If you do not "own" the code that is being stripped, you can manually reference a class/method so the Linker does not strip it:

```
[Preserve]
public static class LinkerPreserve
{
    static LinkerPreserve()
    {
        throw new Exception(typeof(My.Library.SomeManager).FullName);
    }
}
```

If you own the code, you can apply the `PreserveAttribute` to the class.

```
[Preserve]
public class SomeManager
{
    ~~~~
}
```

You can also apply the `--linkskip=ASSEMBLY` in the build options...

Refer the docs for details:

- https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.PreserveAttribute/

It take full control of the Mono linking process you can create a custom linking config file:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker

Comment: Ah, I think that must be it. I'll try using `PreserveAttribute` on my manager classes and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I actually decided to change the linker setting to SdkOnly which seemed to fix the problem. I was having more issues after using `PreserveAttribute` unrelated to my services so I just changed the linker setting to avoid all of them.